# How do I set fields inside a javascript object like this one?

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I am new to javascript and I would like to know how it is possible to dive into a java script object and set fields like the one I have posted below. Is it possible for me to say something like

```
$("#pivotGridContainer").dxPivotGrid().datasource.Fields[0].area = X;
```

I have experience with java and c. Am I wrong for thinking that this is possible?

widgets.js

```
   $("#pivotGridContainer").dxPivotGrid({


     dataSource: {
            store: orders,
            fields: [
                { area: 'column', dataField: 'OrderDate', dataType: 'date', groupInterval: 'year' },
                { area: 'column', dataField: 'OrderDate', dataType: 'date', groupInterval: 'quarter' },
                { area: 'column', dataField: 'OrderDate', dataType: 'date', groupInterval: 'month' },
                { area: 'row', dataField: 'ShipCountry' },
                { area: 'row', dataField: 'ShipCity' },
                { area: 'row', dataField: 'ShipName' },
                { area: 'data', summaryType: 'count' }
            ]
        }
    });
```

page.html

```
<html>
     <head>
      some dependencies
     </head>
    <body>
         <div id="pivotGridContainer" style="height:800px; width:1000px;   margin:    0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also one final question. Often I find myself searching through the documentation of these visual tools looking for methods to get and set fields or initialize a new widget. Is it possible to print/return out all methods and fields of a js object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$("#pivotGridContainer").dxPivotGrid()` part of your call is going to return a chainable jQuery object, not an object with dataSource on it.

You can get access the dom element via the `each()` jQuery method

```
$("#pivotGridContainer").dxPivotGrid().each(function(){

});
```

The `this` object in the function will be the DOM node. So you can query anything that has been bound to it. However you will be walking the DOM tree so it's a little more complex than doing `.datasource.Fields[0].area = X`

A better solution would be to manipulate the data before passing it to `dxPivotGrid()`.